# Performing key combinations in connectbot?

Tags: ssh

Does anybody know how to perform key combinations in ConnectBot?

Examples:

`Ctrl+Z`

`Ctrl+F2`

`Ctrl+Alt+Del`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The ConnectBot developers recommend](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/wiki/UsageWithSoftKeyboard) [Full Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hmw.android.fullkeyboard) to issue keyboard shortcuts. But there are also [other keyboards](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard).